# assigning new properties to an element and retrieving them

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some very simple code, but its perplexing me:

```
<textarea loc="'this is a string'" onclick="console.log(this.loc)"></textarea>
```

(you can view it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zddwdLun/))

My code is supposed to:

- Give the textarea an attribute of loc ('this is a string')
- Then, onclick log the loc attribute by accessing itself, then the newly made attribute

This odd glitch is confusing me, and solving this is vital to finishing a program I've been working on. Its so simple, yet so confusing. Any ideas of how to log the textareas location to the console?

Comment: Use `this.getAttribute('loc')`. Properties aren't attributes.

Comment: The attribute loc. Loc is not typically an HTML attribute so I called it newly made.

Comment: You really should be using a data attribute instead of inventing your own attributes.

Comment: You should use `data-loc="value"` and `this.dataset.loc`

Comment: data attribute? Please elaborate. This sounds very interesting and useful. Also your getAttribute method worked well.

Comment: Also, why is using the data attribute better than inventing my own attributes?

Comment: See [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: That cleared things up. Thanks for the guidance, this will help me on my project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since this question hasn't been closed with an answer I might as well make one with Bergi's knowledge. To get one of an elements attributes simply use:

```
this.getAttribute("loc")
```